# What is the proper way to set the constraint for the sign in page iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a sign in form in iOS

[image]

It looks fine on the storyboard, but it looks very bad in the simulator.

[image]

What are the basic **constraints** I need to apply to my components to make it look like the storyboard?

Comment: It looks like you want your items to be centred horizontally, so that constraint would be the starting point and then place whatever vertical constraints you want between the items. Essentially you need enough constraints so that autolayout can determine a location and size for each element. Some elements have an intrinsic size; others you may have to specify the size (or you may want to specify a size)

Comment: Do I select all the components? and then horizontal center them? Do I need to apply individual constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Not all , but from image you should

- give all components centerX constraint to superView
- all except the top image ( has it to superView ) should have a top constraint to the above component
- the textfield's views should have a height , a proportional width constraint to the superView ( and that if you not set leading and trailing constraints for them)
- read the red warning to know the current problem and fix it

Think of every compoent as a frame x,y,width,height

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187081/discussion-on-answer-by-sh-khan-what-is-the-proper-way-to-set-the-constraint-for).